# Verificação da senha no where do select

Tags: php

Alterei a segurança do meu site. Para isso alterei o formato ao guardar a senha de `sha1` para `password_hash`.

Com o `sha1` para validar o login fazia desta forma:

```
if((isset($_POST['nome'])) && (isset($_POST['senha']))){

        $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nome']); //Escapar de caracteres especiais, como aspas, prevenindo SQL injection
        $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha']);
        $senha = sha1($senha);

        //Buscar na tabela usuario o usuário que corresponde com os dados digitado no formulário
        $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome = '$usuario' && senha = '$senha' && situacoe_id = '1' LIMIT 1";
        $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
        $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);
        ....
        ....
}
```

Mas agora não estou a conseguir validar com o formato de `password_hash`, estou a tentar desta forma:

```
if((isset($_POST['nome'])) && (isset($_POST['senha']))){

        $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nome']); //Escapar de caracteres especiais, como aspas, prevenindo SQL injection
        $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha']);
        $senha = password_verify($senha);

        //Buscar na tabela usuario o usuário que corresponde com os dados digitado no formulário
        $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome = '$usuario' && senha = '$senha' && situacoe_id = '1' LIMIT 1";
        $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
        $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);
        ....
        ....
}
```

Mas não valida. Também tentei desta forma, alterando esta linha `$senha = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`

Comment: Pra você utilizar o password_verify vc tem que ter salvo a senha usando o  password_hash, vc fez isso?

Comment: @Kayo Bruno Sim, tanto a nível do insert como update está a ser salvo usando  password_hash, exemplo de uma password `$2y$10$NezuGRRDGZQSExsHjtDDnO85AF3/BkqeDYFSOW3c6hNJaMg6Zbe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) recebe **dois parâmetros** e retorna um valor **booleano**: verdadeiro, se o hash da senha (não do hash dela!) passada no primeiro parâmetro bate com o hash passado no segundo, e falso caso contrário.

Dessa forma, assumindo que o campo `senha` da tabela `usuarios` é um hash válido da senha do usuário, o uso correto seria:

```
$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nome']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha']);

$result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome = '$usuario' && situacoe_id = '1' LIMIT 1";
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);

if (password_verify($senha, $usuario['senha'])) {
  // Login bem sucedido...
} else {
  // Senhas não conferem...
}
```

O procedimento é o seguinte:

- Pegar o hash da senha do usuário, guardado no banco de dados;
- Aplicar `password_verify` usando a senha recebida na request e o hash que pegamos;
- Usar o retorno da função para validar o login.